# Get Records 30 minutes before date and time

Tags: php, mysql

Been trying to get this to work for 2 days and this is frustrating me.

Trying to get records 30 minutes before a date/time (Format in database is datetime).

This is what I have:

```
select id 
from tbl_events 
WHERE DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL -30 MINUTE) = DATE_FORMAT(start, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')
```

What the heck am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: perhaps removing `-30` minutes is equivalent to adding `30` minutes

Comment: Your query will match only those records from _exactly_ 30 minutes back... you'd be extremely lucky to match a record... edit: and maybe @Cid has a point here as well^^

Comment: `WHERE start = DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 MINUTE)` Or maybe `WHERE start <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 MINUTE)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SELECT date BETWEEN dates with interval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44857375/select-date-between-dates-with-interval)

Answer (score 2):

You already use the function `DATE_SUB()` so within that function you can simply use `INTERVAL 30 MINUTE` without the minus sign.

You also don't have to format `start` if it is a datetime or timestamp field.

Finally you shouldn't use `=` because times are hardly every exactly equal.

This gives this query:

```
select id 
from tbl_events 
WHERE start < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 MINUTE)
```

Probably. It's not extremely clear what you're trying to do.